# Boost bjam Jamfile import statement

Tags: c++, boost, bjam

I have a complex C++ application that is building via bjam (V2) utility (along with some shellscripts to bootstrap the environment)

In the Jamroot file , there are "include(s)" , some of which are documented as builtin , but a lot look like "custom" stuff.

I'm trying to add unit tests and I am having difficulty understanding the lifecycle of what bjam is actually doing. The official error is that the linker is failing to "find" libraries that really should be visible , bc they're used at compile time and I do see "mention" of them in Jamroot. Soo I'm not sure if I need to explicitly declare something in the unit-test target to *nudge* it or what? Do i have to follow some special "order" ? Does anybody have any expirience with this? Basically i have a bunch of unittest_someclass.cpp files in same dir where my code is and i want them to compile/run as part of the build. Each test has own main function that will setup and run the tests.

I thought all i had to do was `import test;` and all requirements would be inherited from parent Jamroot, but looks like this is not the case?

Boost version is 1.53

Here's a code sample of what I added in Jamfile

```
 custom_lib_target my_project_lib
     :
   /boost//headers
   /some_other_stuff//etc
   ...
     :
    <warn_extra>off
    ...etc...
     ;

   #my unit_test target 
 exe boost_tester
   :
  my_project_lib
   ;

 unit-test test_all
 : [ glob unittest*.cpp ] boost_tester
 ;
```

Comment: There's nothing magical about boost-build. If you need some special rule you should import some jam file which implements it. Typical installation of boost-build will have a `/usr/share/boost-build` directory somewhere with all kinds of helpful jam files in it.

Comment: In particular, to use your `unit-test` rule (deprecated) you should `import testing ;` (https://github.com/boostorg/build/blob/develop/src/tools/testing.jam)

Comment: I have the import but when i run the unit test target i get a lot of errors form ld: libwhatever.so , needed by /usr/local/whatever not foudn try using -rpath or -rpath-link , i have these declared in parent Jamroot , which can build everything but when i try to build subproject , i guess i have to mention it explicitly ...

Comment: Clearly you want to pass all the relevant compile and link flags through as required.

Comment: That is exactly what i am trying to figure out how to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was not so much with boost test framework (although this could be better documented) , the problem was with the linker not being able to find debug variants of various libraries to link against. (Reading the warnings helped.) So while the build worked for the project when run from root , it failed for sub-projects, for example while trying to run unit tests individually. I was able to fix it by hardcoding (not ideal but it works) the paths to debug variants as follows:

`lib my_lib : : <file>/path/to/my_lib-d.so <variant>debug`

Then you use it in your test build like so

`unit-test my_test : [ glob unittest*.cpp ] my_lib : ;`

I'm not familiar enough with Boost.Build V2 at this point, so I don't know how to make this more "elegant"